# access variable from inner function

Tags: javascript

```
    var urihost;
var result =  page.evaluate(function () {
        ............
        "set urihost value from here"
        ............
});
```

How can I access urihost from the inner functions, Making it global does not work either

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KGLzj/

Comment: It should work as is, if not, please setup your code on jsfiddle

Comment: what does the `page.evaluate` function do exactly?

Comment: The fiddle edited into the question by @SimonPlus actually works. It logs correct result to the console.

Comment: I am using phantomjs. I just found this http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/issues/detail?id=132, I am not clear what it means yet

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what have you come up with (we'll need to see your code) and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine but I see that you have something that looks like a callback function. It is possible that `urihost` does not yet have a value after assigning result - because the callback function hasn't been called, and `urihost` hasn't been assigned a value.

Can you post more of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding your question...

But your code should work the way it is, see **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dPXjn/)**

```
// Setup page object:
var page = {
    evaluate: function(func) {
        // Don't forget to call the function...
        func();
    }
};

// The variable you want to change:
var urihost = 1;

// Execute now...
var result = page.evaluate(function () {
    urihost = 2;
});

// The alerted result will be 2
alert(urihost);​
```